# Http client cant get json data from web server

Tags: c#, json, api, windows-phone-8, asynchttpclient

```
       private async void get()
       {
            string URL ="http://8tracks.com/mix_sets/all.json?include=mixes?api_key=05570e44383665661d8edeeb5d4f07d415e14b4a";
            HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
            String response = await c.GetStringAsync(URL);
            textbook.Text = response;
```

hello even one... I have been trying to pull data from a web server using the code above and I was unable to get it to work. I am new to this and I have tried other similar patterns but it wont work either. can someone write a code that will work showing me how it is done? bob tabor used this pattern I put above for his around me app tutorial and it works

Comment: Your url is missing the closing quote and semicolon, was that a copy-paste error?

Comment: your code is fine for getting the data from server. just make your code compile. Can you tell us what error/problem you are facing ?

Comment: thanks for that... but that's a mistake I make as I am composing this question. the application compiles with the closing quotes and every code in written correctly but it doesn't get the data from the webserver.

Comment: put a break point on `textbook.Text = response;` and Check your Response variable.for its value. I just checked your code. It is working fine.

Comment: I have done that and I wasn't getting any string. you can try it in visual studio and see for your self 

Comment: @thugsodier I saw it bro. and I am getting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think I am kidding with you :) Check below for proof I haven't Photoshoped it :)
.[image]

`For ThugSoldier` :- Hey, I got your Code zip file. You know what I got from your code is you are really don't know a thing about mobile development. So my suggestion for you is - before trying anything on by yourself, first go through quickly over the resources/topic by this you will get a rough idea what you are reading about. Don't take it in wrong way I just wanted to help you by all means. As I faced all this too.

**If you have put the whole code before then you ans is just one comment away :)**

Your Code that I got from you mailed zip File.

// Xaml Code

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="-191,-181,191,181">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform TranslateX="300" TranslateY="200"/>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock Name="xt" FontSize="25" Text=""/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

// **MainPage .cs** code.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void web()
    {
        String url = "http://8tracks.com/mix_sets/all.json?include=mixesapi_key=05570e44383665661d8edeeb5d4f07d415e14b4a";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        xt.Text = result;
    }
}
```

**Problem** :-

`In the above Code actually you have not called the web() Method from anywhere - means you have to invoke web() method. By using Some Button Click Event.`

**SOLUTION** :-

I have made Button in Xaml and added a ClickEvent to it. that is available in MainPage .cs backend class. And What happen next whenever you click on the button your event will be called and hence your web() method. That will get your data.

**Full Code** :-

**Xaml** :-

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="-191,-181,191,181">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform TranslateX="300" TranslateY="200"/>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock Name="xt" FontSize="25" Text=""/>
        
        <Button Content="ClickMe" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
        
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.cs Code :-

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void web()
    {
        String url = "http://8tracks.com/mix_sets/all.json?include=mixesapi_key=05570e44383665661d8edeeb5d4f07d415e14b4a";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        xt.Text = result;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        web();
    }
}
```

Now you are on done :- run the app => click on the button => enjoy the result in your TextBox.

Suggestion :- Download some basic samples of windows phone apps run them locally. see there code.

Just contact me on my for any future help/guidance :) Cheers :D

Comment: So why don't it work for me? Thanks for confirming it works... something is wrong somewhere

Comment: @thugsodier First check is internet working on your Emulator/Device. and also put this getstringasync(url) call in try catch. also put your whole code in your question. I will check for it.

Comment: Internet is working... does it have anything to do with app permission?

Comment: @thugsodier Check is ID_CAP_NETWORKING is enabled in WMAppMenifestFile under capability section ?

Comment: did you test it on windows phone 8 SDK? because I did it on windows phone 8.1... the manifest settings differ between 8 and 8.1

Comment: I have tested it on both :) actually i have both version targeted project opened. I have ID_CAP_NETWORKING enabled on both. Can you try it in new projects ?

Comment: let me try making a new project. I started with 2013 it wasn't working so I installed 2014 preview and its still not working.

Comment: @thugsodier Can you make zip of your sample project and share with me. I will see what is going wrong.

Comment: how do i share with you? I dont know how to send the file here...

Comment: @thugsodier send me zip files at tanujsharma59 at gmail dot com.

Comment: lol silly me... yeah I am just starting and incompletely forgot I was suppose to call the method... thanks.